# How to use Rails.vim and spork?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, rspec, spork

If I'm in a rails project, editing with rails.vim, how can I get :Rake to run the specs through Spork?

Its largely just a matter of making :Rake aware of the project's specs/spec.opts file via the "-o" flag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that Rails.vim will use Spork if you add the `--drb` option to your spec.opts file automatically.

Comment: Just so everyone knows, in Rspec 2, rspec.opts has been replaced with .rspec (or ~/.rspec). But the --drb option should still work the same.